# How could potions be correctly made following the standard instructions?

Tags: harry-potter, severus-snape, potions

In *Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince*, Horace Slughorn, the former potions master, returns to teach at Hogwarts. In his class, unlike that of Snape's, students follow the standard potions book, *Advanced
Potion-Making* by Libatius Borage.

However, following the instructions from the book, even Hermione is unable to prepare a perfectly correct potion. Only Harry succeeds, and that is just because he follows the instructions given by Snape in his copy of the book.

Given that Slughorn had been the potions master for decades before Snape, and that the book by Libatius Borage was probably followed for a similarly long duration, how did any one in the current generation who worked in the field of potions do it correctly? Wouldn't they have learnt from these texts themselves? If this was not the case, why weren't the standard texts updated?

Or, did the arrival of Snape redefine what "correct" was? If so, and that experienced and respected potioneers like Slughorn could recognize it, why didn't everyone change their way of doing things?

Comment: Large elements of this question are covered by the dupe.

Comment: Incidentally, the fact that nobody did especially well in Snape's classes suggests that Snape taught the standard recipes too.  He might have taught some of his tricks to his favoured students, but probably not to everyone else.